# How To Measure The Size of gRPC Response

Tags: go, grpc, rpc, grpc-python, grpc-go

I am trying come up with better ways to deal with the 4mb message size limit in grpc. I need a way to measure the size of the grpc response received on client side. When the response exceeds 4mb limit grpc shows a error message like:

> could not greet: rpc error: code = ResourceExhausted desc = grpc: received message larger than max (74000087 vs. 4194304)

with "74000087" being the actual size of the response. How is this calculated? Is there a way to get this value?

I have gone through multiple articles on this topic but could find nothing? Can someone please help? Thanks.

My implementation is using golang

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out a way to do this. The solution is to encode the gRPC response into the `byte` stream, and then calculate the size using  `binary.Size()`

```
func GetGRPCResponseSize(val interface{}, desc string) (int, error) {

    var buff bytes.Buffer
    enc := gob.NewEncoder(&buff)
    err := enc.Encode(val)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error("encode error:", err)
        return 0, err
    }
    return binary.Size(buff.Bytes()), nil
}
```

Comment: This is not a precise answer. You are just predicting what would be the compression, by doing a gob encoding offline. There is no guarantee that this would be the size of the network payload.

Answer (score 6):

#### Computing message size

As per the [proto docs](https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto#Size),

> `func Size(m Message) int`
>
> Size returns the size in bytes of the wire-format encoding of m.

#### gRPC message size limits

Also, it might be useful in your case to consider setting [`grpc.MaxCallRecvMsgSize`](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc#MaxCallRecvMsgSize) as a `grpc.CallOption` to manage limits.